# Display the corresponding temperature logos with "simpleweatherjs" API

Tags: javascript, jquery, weather, weather-api

I relied on this exemple : https://codepen.io/fleeting/pen/xklfq and i want to display logo for the next days, i tried to add this code to display the next days temperatures:

```
for(var i=0;i<weather.forecast.length;i++) {
    html += '<p class="days">'+'<span class="d">'+weather.forecast[i].day+'</span>'+'<span class="val">'+weather.forecast[i].high+'</span>'+'</p>';
}
```

i displayed them but i don't know ho to implemtent the logos ?

The complete **html** code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: 'Austin, TX',
    woeid: '',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
      html = '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.code+'"></i> '+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
      html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
      html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li>';
      html += '<li>'+weather.wind.direction+' '+weather.wind.speed+' '+weather.units.speed+'</li></ul>';

      //My add here
      for(var i=0;i<weather.forecast.length;i++) {
          html += '<p class="days">'+'<span class="d">'+weather.forecast[i].day+'</span>'+'<span class="val">'+weather.forecast[i].high+'</span>'+'</p>';
      }

      $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The logos are contained in the CSS as per your example.
You can simply add an <i> with the correct class in your loop

eg. 
html += '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.forecast[i].code+'"></i>

Comment: Yes that's it, it works now, thanks, please add the code in an answer to accept it and also for your reputation ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logos are contained in the `CSS` used in the code example on CodePen.
If you have the `CSS` referenced in your `HTML`, you can simply add the following:

```
html += '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.forecast[i].code+'"></i></h2>'
```

to your `for` loop.

So your code would look like the following :

```
//My add here
for(var i=0;i<weather.forecast.length;i++) {
  html += '<p class="days">'+'<span class="d">'+weather.forecast[i].day+'</span>'+'<span class="val">'+weather.forecast[i].high+'</span>'+'</p>';
  html += '<h2><i class="icon-'+weather.forecast[i].code+'"></i></h2>';
}
```

Comment: yes, just a last question, have an idea how to replace the logos ? if i want to replace them with another .png ? or with those : https://codepen.io/joshbader/pen/EjXgqr